# Website displays perfect everywhere but in Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css

I am building a website for my dad and everything is well displayed everywhere but in the Chrome browser for mobile (Tested on my Android Lollipop phone).

I have forced the width to 1000px so nothing should resize or scale but it seems like it is getting scaled on Chrome for Android. Firefox for Android is displaying everything fine.

To be honest, I have no idea where to look for so I will share a direct url to the page I am talking about : http://tinyurl.com/pu5rmee

Chrome for Android (bad scaled) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7JrI.jpg
Firefox for Android (perfect) : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pen28.jpg

Thanks

Comment: for mobile browsers in the head of you document  you need to add the viewport meta tag so you have control of the initial scale (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">)

Comment: @Tasos Thanks you ! It seems to have fixed the issue ! However, on page load, the zoom is insane ! How can I make it not zoomed :) (aka in 100% :) )

Comment: you can set a maximum scale (<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">)

Comment: or scale it down (initial-scale=0.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome for Mobile increases a font-size for better site readability. To disable this feature add `viewport` meta tag inside your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

or by the CSS:

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
}
```

Alternatively (not recommended, "old" way is) you can set the parent element `max-height` to some unreasonable big number, for example `max-height: 999999px`.

Comment: Thanks you ! It seems to have fixed the issue ! However, on page load, the zoom is insane ! How can I make it not zoomed :) (aka in 100% :) )

Comment: @Jamesst20 I looked at your page from my smartphone and I didn't see anything unnaturally zoomed.

Comment: The css has no effect on my mobile sadly. I have removed the initial-scale=1 and now the zoom is perfect on my mobile in Chrome & Opera but in Firefox it is zoomed :O